# Calculating number of days since a particular date not working as expected

Tags: c, leap-year

I wrote a function in C to calculate how many days it has been since January 1, 2000. However, it doesn't work correctly for some years (e.g. it works for May 5, 2020, but not for May 5, 2029). For some years it determines the number of days correctly, for others 1 day less, and for some two or three days less. Which part of the code could cause this problem?

```
bool isLeapYear(int y) {
    if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}

int days_since(int y, int m, int d)
{   int m_days[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int leap_count = 0;
    int years_index = y-2000;
    for (int i=2001; i<=y; i++){
        if(isLeapYear(i))
            leap_count ++;
    }
    int add_years = 366 * (leap_count) + 365 * (years_index-leap_count);

    int add_months = 0;
    if (isLeapYear(y))
        m_days[1] = 29;
    
    for (int i=0; i<m-1; i++)
        add_months += m_days[i];
    
    int add_days = d-1;

    int total_days = add_years + add_months + add_days;

    return total_days;
}
```

Comment: Please show the `isLeapYear()` function.

Comment: Dates in January and most of February haven't had a leap day regardless of year.

Comment: @WeatherVane  edited the question to also show isLeapYear().

Comment: Why don't you just conver to Unix time and then calculate the number of days from the number of seconds (the difference of Unix epoch)

Comment: Thanks. The loop seems incorrect. Should `for (int i=2001; i<=y; i++)` be `for (int i=2000; i<y; i++)` ? You haven't reckoned year 2000 (a leap year) and you've reckoned the current year twice (because you overwrite 28 with 29 in the array).

Comment: @WeatherVane to be honest, I thought the behavior would be the same in case of both loops, but now that you mentioned the double calculation for the current year I can see the difference. The calculations seem to be correct for the first loop, thank you for the help!

Comment: This `for (int i=0; i<m-1; i++)` doesn't look right either. If month is 0-based use `for (int i=0; i<m; i++)`. So, for January the loop will not run and you'll add only the date. For Fenruary the loop will run once (January's days) and then add the date. But your version won't use the January days, in Februrary etc.

Comment: Tip: simplify `int add_years = 366 * (leap_count) + 365 * (years_index-leap_count);` --> `int add_years = leap_count + 365 * years_index;`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't this mean neglecting the days in the given month, and only taking days from January until the month before?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in the [wikipedia article on Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: @NareAvetisyan no, beacuse you add the date (in the month).

Comment: Surely you don't have to test every year from 2001 onwards to see whether it is a leap year.  You can calculate how many there are more directly than that loop.  Don't forget that 2000 was a leap year.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with February 29th in the middle of the year is a pain and OP's code has troubles with that too.

I do not see a simple fix of OP's code.

Instead, move leap day to the end of the year by making March the first month and January/February the last months of the previous year.  That's what the [Romans did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar#:%7E:text=According%20to%20most%20Roman%20accounts,days%20before%20the%20next%20year.) and then the 8th month is **Oct**ober and the 10th month is **Dec**ember.  This simplifies much code by putting leap day concerns at the year's end.
Notice `days_since_March1[]` below is the same for leap years and non-leap years and the leap year calculation is simple.

```
#include <assert.h>

#define JANUARY 1
#define MARCH 3
#define DECEMBER 12
#define MONTHS_PER_YEAR 12
#define GREGORIAN_FIRST_FULL_YEAR 1583
#define EPOCH_2000Jan1 730426

int days_since2000Jan1(int y, int m, int d) {
  assert(y >= GREGORIAN_FIRST_FULL_YEAR);
  assert(m >= JANUARY && m <= DECEMBER);
  if (m < MARCH) {
    m += MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
    y--;
  }
  int months_since_March = m - MARCH;
  static const short days_since_March1[12] = {0, 31, 61, 92, 122, 153, 184, 214,
      245, 275, 306, 337};
  return y * 365 + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400
      + days_since_March1[months_since_March] + d - EPOCH_2000Jan1;
}
```

Comment: For those who like a less restrictive month and a formula vs a table: `int days_since2000Jan1(int y, int m, int d) {
  assert(y >= GEGORIAN_FIRST_FULL_YEAR);
  y += m / MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
  m %= MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
  while (m < MARCH) {
    m += MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
    y--;
  }
  int days_since_March1 = (979 * m - 2919) >> 5;  // About 30.6 days/month
  return y * DAYS_PER_COMMON_YEAR + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400
      + days_since_March1 + d - EPOCH_2000Jan1;
}`

Comment: Is there any way to fill an array with these and then separate out the good days from the bad days? `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3, [Good days](https://georgejziogas.medium.com/every-day-above-ground-is-a-great-day-6b11d0dbc20a#:~:text=It%20simply%20means%20that%20you,days%20their%20life%20will%20include.)

Comment: I've met a few opal miners who'd disagree with the premise, or at least the title, of that article... `:-)`