# Function calculating work days between two dates not working as expected

Tags: c, function

**EDIT**: Including all of the code now, apparently the problem could be outside `countDays()`.

I am writing a function which takes as input two dates and returns a struct with two variables: `m_TotalDays` (total number of days between the two dates) and `m_WorkDays` (the total days minus weekends and specific national holidays). However, the calculation for `m_WorkDays` is wrong when the two given dates' years are different, and for those whose years are the same, it gives one day less then the correct answer.

The function also makes use of 2 other functions `isWorkDay()` and `totalDays()`, however, I am sure the problem does not come from these functions. I believe the mistake must be in the `for` loop in `countDays()`, but I don't seem to find where the issue might be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int m_days[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

typedef struct
{
    int m_TotalDays;
    int m_WorkDays;
} TResult;

bool isDayValid(int y, int m, int d);
bool isLeapYear(int y);
int totalDays(int y, int m, int d);
bool isWorkDay(int y, int m, int d);
TResult countDays (int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2);

int main()
{
    int y1 = 2023;
    int m1 = 1;
    int d1 = 1;

    int y2 = 2023;
    int m2 = 12;
    int d2 = 31;

    countDays(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2);
}

bool isLeapYear(int y) {
    if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool isDayValid(int y, int m, int d)
{
    int months_31[7] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 };
    int months_30[4] = { 4, 6, 9, 11 };

    if (y < 2000)    //year is invalid
        return false;
    if (m < 1 || m > 12)    //month is invalid
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)     //day is invalid
        if (m == months_30[i])
            if (d > 31)
                return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (m == months_30[i])
            if (d > 30)
                return false;
    if (!(isLeapYear(y)) && m == 2 && d > 28)    //if february > 28 on a normal year
        return false;
    else if ((isLeapYear(y)) && m == 2 && d > 29)    //if february > 29 on a leap year
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int totalDays(int y, int m, int d)
{
    if (isDayValid(y, m, d))
    {
        int leap_count = 0;
        int years_index = y - 2000;
        for (int i = 2000; i < y; i++) {
            if (isLeapYear(i))
                leap_count++;
        }
        int add_years = leap_count + 365 * (years_index);

        int add_months = 0;
        if (isLeapYear(y))
            m_days[1] = 29;

        for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
            add_months += m_days[i];

        int add_days = d - 1;

        int total_days = add_years + add_months + add_days;

        //printf("Days since: %d\n", total_days);
        return total_days;
    }
}

bool isWorkDay(int y, int m, int d)
{
    int day_in_week = totalDays(y, m, d) % 7;

    //printf("Day in week: %d\n", day_in_week);

    if ((day_in_week == 0) || (day_in_week == 1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((m == 1 && d == 1) ||
        (m == 5 && (d == 1 || d == 8)) ||
        (m == 7 && (d == 5 || d == 6)) ||
        (m == 9 && d == 28) ||
        (m == 10 && d == 28) ||
        (m == 11 && d == 17) ||
        (m == 12 && (d == 24 || d == 25 || d == 26)))
    {
        //printf("not work day\n"); 
        return false; 
    } 
    //printf("work day\n");
    return true;
}

TResult countDays(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2)
{
    TResult res = { 0, 0 };

    if (y2 > y1 || (y2 == y1 && (m2 > m1 || (m2 == m1 && d2 >= d1))))
    {
        int total_days1 = totalDays(y1, m1, d1);
        int total_days2 = totalDays(y2, m2, d2);
        res.m_TotalDays = (total_days2 - total_days1) + 1;

        int nonWorkDays = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= res.m_TotalDays; i++) {
            if (!(isWorkDay(y1, m1, d1))) {
                nonWorkDays++;
            }
            if (d1 < d2)
                d1++;
            if (d1 < m_days[m1 - 1]) {
                d1++;
            } else {
                d1 = 1;
                if (m1 < 12) {
                    m1++;
                } else {
                    m1 = 1;
                    y1++;
                }
            }
        }
        res.m_WorkDays = res.m_TotalDays - nonWorkDays;

        printf("m_TotalDays: %d\n", res.m_TotalDays);
        printf("m_WorkDays: %d\n", res.m_WorkDays);

        return res;
    }
    TResult invalidRes = { -1, -1 };
    return invalidRes;
}
```

Comment: How do you handle leap days?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added the function i use to calculate leap years. i use it in totalDays() where i calculate the days between the given date and 2000-01-01 (the task i'm working on specifies that the years should be counted from this date)

Comment: Look carefully at `for (int i=0; i<=res.m_TotalDays; i++) {`. Generally speaking, if you start a loop at `i = 0`, the terminating condition should be `i < total` (not `i <= total`); the `<=` test should be used for loops that start at `i = 1`. So, for 42 TotalDays, your `for` loop will run 43 times and, thus, you are likely incrementing the `nonWorkDays` value once more than you should be.

Comment: ... hard to say if that's the *only* problem without more code, though. Even though you seem confident your other functions work, nobody can test your code - and any fixes - without them.

Comment: Did you consider using `mktime` and `struct tm` and incrementing just `tm_sec` with one day of seconds?

Comment: Also, I think the way you handle leap years is over simplified. By just adding 1 to the total days, your tests for a working day using `y1,m1,d1` will go haywire, as those calendar values will get to be wrong for a leap year.

Comment: Looks a lot like OP's [post of yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77446492/2410359) that is still open.

Comment: @Nare Avetisyan, "makes use of 2 other functions isWorkDay() and totalDays(), however, I am sure the problem does not come from these functions." is incorrect.  Try `#include <time.h>
int main() {
 for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
  struct tm tm = {.tm_year = 2000-1900, .tm_mon = 1-1, .tm_mday = count+1, .tm_hour = 12};
  mktime(&tm);
  int y = totalDays(tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday);
  if (count != y) {
   printf("totalDays(%d, %d, %d) --> %d, expect %d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, y, count);
   break;
  }
 }
}` fails March 1, 2001.

Comment: Small style note: at the end of `countDays` you should just be able to return. compound literal: `return (Result){ -1, -1 };`

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**`totalDays()` changes the `m_days[]` table**

With `if (isLeapYear(y)) m_days[1] = 29;` the `m_days[]` table is changed.  This is OK if `totalDays()` is only ever called once, but with multiple calls, changing with the table creates problems when subsequent calls are not a leap year.

Alternative code [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77447296/2410359) in OP's prior open question.

**Missing return**

In `totalDays()`, when `isDayValid(y, m, d)` is false, the function does not return any value.  This implies code was not compiled with all warnings enabled.  Save time.  [Enable them all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/2410359).

**Wrong code**

Following code error rapidly found by enabling all warnings.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    // if (m == months_30[i])
    if (m == months_31[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handling of leap years is incorrect: you modify the global array `m_days` as a side effect of the function `totalDays()` and make February have 29 days if the function is called at least once for a leap year, which may produce an erroneous result for the subsequent calls and causes problems in `countDays` as you use the `m_days` array to enumerate all days spanning the period, potentially omitting Feb 29 occurrences if neither the first nor the last year is a leap year or counting extra ones otherwise.

There are other simpler errors such as `d1` being incremented once `if (d1 < d2)` and another time `if (d1 < m_days[m1 - 1])`...

Also `m_TotalDays` and `m_WorkDays` include both the first and last days. Is this the expected behavior?

A simpler solution for the leap year problem is to use a function `int monthDays(int y, int m)` instead of a global array that cannot be always correct.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int m_TotalDays;
    int m_WorkDays;
} TResult;

int monthDays(int y, int m);
bool isDayValid(int y, int m, int d);
bool isLeapYear(int y);
int totalDays(int y, int m, int d);
bool isWorkDay(int y, int m, int d);
TResult countDays(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int y1 = 2023;
    int m1 = 1;
    int d1 = 1;

    int y2 = 2023;
    int m2 = 12;
    int d2 = 31;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d/%d/%d", &d1, &m1, &y1) != 3)
            return 1;
        if (argc > 2) {
            if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d/%d/%d", &d2, &m2, &y2) != 3)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    TResult res = countDays(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2);

    printf("%d/%d/%d - %d/%d/%d: ", d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2);
    if (res.m_TotalDays < 0) {
        printf("invalid dates\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("m_TotalDays: %d, m_WorkDays: %d\n",
               res.m_TotalDays, res.m_WorkDays);
        return 0;
    }
}

int monthDays(int y, int m) {
    static int const m_days[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (m < 1 || m > 12)
        return -1;
    if (m == 2)
        return 28 + isLeapYear(y);
    else
        return m_days[m - 1];
}

bool isLeapYear(int y) {
    return (y % 4 == 0 && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0));
}

bool isDayValid(int y, int m, int d) {
    return (y >= 2000 && m >= 1 && m <= 12 && d >= 1 && d <= monthDays(y, m));
}

int totalDays(int y, int m, int d) {
    if (isDayValid(y, m, d)) {
        int years_count = y - 2000;
        int total_days = 365 * years_count;
        for (int i = 2000; i < y; i++) {
            if (isLeapYear(i))
                total_days++;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
            total_days += monthDays(y, i);

        total_days += d - 1;
        //printf("totalDays(%d, %d, %d) -> %d\n", y, m, d, total_days);
        return total_days;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

bool isWorkDay(int y, int m, int d) {
    int day_in_week = totalDays(y, m, d) % 7;

    //printf("Day in week: %d\n", day_in_week);
    // Jan 1st 2000 was a Saturday
    if (day_in_week == 0 || day_in_week == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    // enumerate the national holidays in the Tcheck Republic
    if ((m == 1 && d == 1)
    ||  (m == 5 && (d == 1 || d == 8))
    ||  (m == 7 && (d == 5 || d == 6))
    ||  (m == 9 && d == 28)
    ||  (m == 10 && d == 28)
    ||  (m == 11 && d == 17)
    ||  (m == 12 && (d == 24 || d == 25 || d == 26))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

TResult countDays(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2) {
    TResult res = { -1, -1 };
    int total_days1 = totalDays(y1, m1, d1);
    int total_days2 = totalDays(y2, m2, d2);

    if (total_days1 >= 0 && total_days2 >= 0 && total_days2 >= total_days1) {
        // include both the first and last days: is this correct?
        res.m_TotalDays = (total_days2 - total_days1) + 1;
        res.m_WorkDays = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < res.m_TotalDays; i++) {
            if (isWorkDay(y1, m1, d1)) {
                res.m_WorkDays++;
            }
            // enumerate the next day
            if (d1 < monthDays(y1, m1)) {
                d1++;
            } else {
                d1 = 1;
                if (m1 < 12) {
                    m1++;
                } else {
                    m1 = 1;
                    y1++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ for i in {2000..2023} ; do ./231111-days 1/1/$i 31/12/$i ; done
1/1/2000 - 31/12/2000: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2001 - 31/12/2001: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2002 - 31/12/2002: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2003 - 31/12/2003: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2004 - 31/12/2004: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 255
1/1/2005 - 31/12/2005: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2006 - 31/12/2006: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2007 - 31/12/2007: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2008 - 31/12/2008: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2009 - 31/12/2009: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2010 - 31/12/2010: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2011 - 31/12/2011: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2012 - 31/12/2012: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2013 - 31/12/2013: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2014 - 31/12/2014: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2015 - 31/12/2015: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2016 - 31/12/2016: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2017 - 31/12/2017: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2018 - 31/12/2018: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
1/1/2019 - 31/12/2019: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2020 - 31/12/2020: m_TotalDays: 366, m_WorkDays: 253
1/1/2021 - 31/12/2021: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2022 - 31/12/2022: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 254
1/1/2023 - 31/12/2023: m_TotalDays: 365, m_WorkDays: 252
```